# How to navigate in JSF page between WAR files?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a four WAR files which are modules of application. How I can navigate between the pages? For example If I have a module which displays list of users and I want to click in a user's profile, how I can point the address of the module which holds the user's profile JSF page?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use plain HTML `<a>` elements in JSF:

```html
<a href="/othermodule/page.xhtml">Go to page in other module</a>
```

Or if it runs at a different domain:

```html
<a href="http://otherdomain.com/page.xhtml">Go to page in other domain</a>
```